# Bsod UNEXPECTED_STORE_EXCEPTION

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, ssd, bsod

(Sorry for my bad english)

I have a problem for months with my Windows 10. Firstly, my wireless card (Qualcomm AR922X/TP-Link WN951N) crashes frequently (probably because of the driver provided by Microsoft).
Then, I have frequently (at least one time by day) a BSOD with the error UNEXPECTED_STORE_EXCEPTION.
I also had the error "DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION".
I was wondering if that's not because of my power supply, but that doesn't seem to be.
I have already try a memtest. It seems that there is no problem with the RAM.
The big problem is that the system freezes ramdomly, both on Linux (installed on a HDD) or Windows 10 (installed on a SSD). The mouse and everything are frozen. Sometimes, my computer crashes directly at the bios display (when I power on my computer).

I do an error scan with HD Tune Pro on the SSD. It reveals that one sector is damaged (0%). But I have a warning with the "Reallocated Event Count" (16) and a "attention" tag with the "Interface CRC Error Client" (131 errors). The software says it may be caused because of a damaged cable.
With the HDD, I also have an "Interface CRC Error Count" attention tag. I'm currently scanning it and the damaged blocks represent 0.6% (15 sectors).

I have updated my Bios and everything on Windows with Windows Update and MSI Live Update.
I have already tried a clean install.

Do you have any idea about this terrible problem ? Thanks in advance ! I'm completly desperate...

When I plug my smartphone, the computer crashes immediately (especially when I activate the router mode on the smartphone). I tried others USB devices and there is no problem with them.

Comment: There seem to be a lot of different causes for that BSOD: Missing BIOS Updates, Harddissk-Problems (mostly SSD), Antivirus Software ... Did you try to reinstall / change your anti virus software? Is the firmware of your ssd up to date?

Comment: You are right ! The firmware of my ssd was not up to date ! I have fixed it immediately (the patch is about power optimisation). I hope this is the solution ! Thank you a lot !

Comment: I still have the problem. Bios is up to date, SSD firmware is up to date, antivirus (Eset Nod32) is up to date but I can try another one.
Windows indicates that "A TCG Command has returned en error." (EnhancedStorage-EhStor-TcgDrv)